# oracle add column to existing table

Tags: oracle

I have already a table in oracle defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE GENERAL_STATISTICS.PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT3
(
  NAME   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  START_TIME  DATE,
  END_TIME    DATE
)
```

What I would like to achieve is add an extra column at the end (as 4th column to the table). I execute:

```
ALTER TABLE PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT3
ADD
(
ROWS_LOADED varchar2(100 BYTE)
);
```

I receive an error "ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option"

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Thank you,

Best Regards

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `alter table` statement.  I just ran it OK in 11G.  The only possible issue I can think of it if you are using a version of Oracle so old that it doesn't recognise the `byte` keyword?

Comment: @TonyAndrews , thanks Tony for looking into it, no i use 11g as well. What's so bizarre here..

Comment: In the `alter` statement you omitted the schema prefix `GENERAL_STATISTICS.` - are you running the command in that schema?

Comment: Correct , in that schema.

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong at all on the face of it.  Maybe try re-typing the `alter` command - maybe it has a cut and pasted invisible character in it!

Comment: No, this is not the case.

Comment: Sorry, can't help any further then!

Answer (score 0):

its for the type of field, you must try to change to another type of data